# get the frontend theme path in magento admin

Tags: magento, path, themes

In my Magento module i upload a CSS file in the backend to use it in my front

I tried this :

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getSkinBaseDir()
```

But it gives different path (admin/front)

In my Block , I got this :

> C:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\skin\frontend\default\default\

And in my Adminhtml/Controller (saving the file) I got this :

> C:\wamp\www\ce_1.6.2.0\skin\adminhtml\default\default

How can I get the same path (front) in the Block and in the Controller ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just force it to the frontend :

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getSkinBaseDir(array('_area' => 'frontend'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer and alternative to Rastaking's answer that will return a URL path rather than a file path:

```
Mage::getModel('core/design_package')->getSkinUrl();
```

This will return something like:

> http://www.yourdomain.com/skin/frontend/your_package/your_skin/

Hope this helps, anyone looking for a similar solution.

Comment: You could use **Mage::getSingleton()** if the class is already instantiated.

Comment: What if you want to get the admin skin url from the frontend? Answer me that and you get a +1.

Comment: Accessing the adminhtml skin path from the frontend? **<?php echo Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseUrl(array('_area'=>'adminhtml')) ?>**... Now, about that +1 :p

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getSkinBaseDir(array('_area' => 'frontend','_package'=>'rwd','_theme'=>'default'));
```